# cron job for backup the database in linux/php

Tags: php, linux, cron

Am new to linux cron job, i am using mysql DB, my database name finaldb, i want to take this database every one hour,

I have folder called dailbackup, in this i have folder by date wise,in this each folder i have backup mysql db file

name like final_db_9.sql (this backup taken at morning 9 am), final_db_13.sql(this backup taken at noon 1pm, like that ,

this process at present am doing manually , is it possible to make it automation , any ideas, suggestions ,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a PHP Script containing the following:

```
$dbFile = 'final_db'.date('H').'.sql.gz';
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // Database Host
$dbUser = 'username'; // Database Username
$dbPass = 'password'; // Database Password
exec( 'mysqldump --host="'.$dbHost.'" --user="'.$dbUser.'" --password="'.$dbPass.'" --add-drop-table "finaldb" | gzip > "'.$dbFile.'"' );
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a php script may create some out of memory errors depending on the php configuration, and also some timeout problem if you call it from an http request.

Comment: Possibly - there are a million variables which will affect the efficacy of this solution (as with alot of solutions). If the script does jam, a combination of `ignore_user_abort(1);` and `set_time_limit(0);` may resolve it.

Comment: @Lucanos: why don't wrap this script running with another one written on ruby, that will be called with another one written on python?

Comment: @Lucanos: I jost wondered why you wrapped the shell one-liner with just one additional (pointless) programming language, and not 3. The more - the better.

Comment: @zerkms: This was an excerpt from a longer backup script I personally use which doesn't just backup the databases, but also the files and does a few other funky things. Out of context it may not make much sense, but, as the OP agrees, it did the job. If you want to propose your own solution, feel free to add another Answer to this Question.

Comment: @zerkms: If you are such a proponent of shell scripts, maybe you should write all of your solutions in nothing but shell.

Comment: @Lucanos: I prefer to choose the most appropriate tool for each task. For such task it is shell-scripts.

Comment: @zerkms: There are too many variables at play to say that there is only one solution here. My solution is based on my experience and has worked well for me. You may have used shell scripts in your solutions. But unless you have had to solve my specific needs with respect to the limitations, etc. imposed by the environment in which that solution was implemented, you cannot say that my solution is wrong. For instance (and as I do not know), would a shell script work on a Windows Server? With PHP I can centrally store my username/password and use it for all scripts - does your solution allow that

Comment: @Lucanos: 1) op wanted specifically linux solution 2) as well as you want to write really **universal** one - just know, that not every linux box has php installed. But each one has shell.

Comment: @zerkms: 1) Agreed. They wanted a Linux solution. I gave an excerpt of a PHP-based (pseudo-)universal one. Easier to reuse than build from scratch, would you not agree? 2) Most Linux boxes running MySQL would be running PHP. Maybe not all, but certainly most (as will most Windows boxes running MySQL). You disagree with me - I get it. But each to their own.

Answer (score 5):

Create somewhere a script to make your rolling backups, like this (untested, but should work):

```
#!/bin/bash

BKPDIR=dailbackup  # You must use absolute path here
DB=finaldb
USERNAME=myusername
PASSWORD=mypassword

BKPFILE=${BKPDIR}/`date +%Y-%m-%d`/final_db_`date +%H`.sql

# Create backup
mysqldump --user=${USERNAME} --password=${PASSWORD} ${DB} | gzip -c > ${BKPFILE}

# Remove older backups (> 7 days),
# unless you want to run out of drive space
find ${BKPDIR} -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Then setup this script to run as an hourly cronjob:

```
crontab -e

0 * * * * /absolute-path-to-where-you-saved-the-script
```

Answer (score 2):

```
crontab -e
```

putting this:

```
the_date='date +%Y%m%d'
the_hour='date +%H'
0 * * * * mysqldump OPTIONS > /dailbackup/`$the_date`/final_db_`$the_hour`.sql
```

the above cron is allow you to backup database every hour and using the `%H` as sql file name

Answer (score 1):

Untested one liner:

```
mysqldump -u*user* -p*password* -P*dbport* -h localhost finaldb > /.../dailbackup/final_db_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M).sql
```

just add it to your cron job or wrap it in a script and you are done

Comment: You can then pipe that to a tar or zip packager

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse, you can do it as long as your mysql server is up and listening :). You will need to make a shell or perl script and use edit the crond using the below command (in Fedora):

```
crontab -e
```

Components of your cron job is ::

1) Path to your script(executable)

2) Minutes(00-59)

3) Hours (00 - 23)

4) Month (01-12)

5) Day (01-31)

6) Day of the week (00 -06 with 00 as Sunday)

Example :: You wat to run test_pl script every day at 1200

entry in crontab will be ::

00 12 * * * /home/jok/test_pl