# Anyone have a good PHP script to run as a cronjob to backup a MySQL database?

Tags: php, database, cron, backup

I've seen some chatter on here about PHP scripts that backup a MySQL database - but there doesn't seem to be a solid solution.

Any help would be GREAT!  I know some of you guys on here are PHP heros :)

Thanks,

NCoder

Comment: Possibly duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422178/cron-job-for-backup-the-database-in-linux-php

Comment: @Fran Verona: reference to the question with **really terrible** checked answer :-S

Comment: @zerkms: Really terrible? Maybe, maybe not. Does my solution answer the question? Yes. Does it also allow (with minor adaptation) for easily triggered ad-hoc backups? Yes. Do you like it? Doesn't seem likely. But does that make it terrible or wrong? Not likely.

Comment: @Lucanos: compare your answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422178/cron-job-for-backup-the-database-in-linux-php/4422338#4422338 --- no additional (superfluous) php, all is done with just shell scripts. As I commented - you can also wrap your script with 2 another, and it will even work, but that doesn't mean it is a way that anyone should follow.

Comment: @zerkms: You also have to recognise that people will prefer to work in a language they are comfortable with. Someone who has never worked with a BASH script would not understand the answer you linked to. Other influences may also enter into the discussion. For instance (and I pose this as I do not know the answer), can you run shell scripts on a Windows Server? I wrote my solution in PHP, which is pretty much universal for that very reason - it is universal. I am happy to discuss it under my Answer, but hijacking this thread or using it to review my answer is not polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice guys.  I found another route here: http://www.dwalker.co.uk/phpmysqlautobackup/readme.html which seems to work great.  Sure it uses a large amount of memory to run the script but it has some great features like emailing the .gz and writing it to the server, or sending it to another FTP.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

NCoder

Answer (score 3):

You don't need php at all - use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: This is something done via SSH I take it?  I'd really like something that writes the backup to the server as a file.  I'm not 100% confident in my SSH abilities...(grin)

Comment: @NCoder: it has nothing to do with ssh. Since you have cron access - you can add a task there, that will backup your databases. And mysqldump writes backups to the file.

Comment: Please take this advice. Writing a PHP script to do it, or writing a PHP script that simply runs mysqldump, are bad ideas.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, why are they bad ideas?  Do companies not run scheduled backups?  @zerkms, is there an example of using the mysqldump?  Thanks

Comment: @NCoder Yes they run scheduled backups, but they use the right tools to do so. Some people record TV shows to watch later, they don't do it by pointing a video camera at their TV when a DVR/VCR is available.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, I like the analogy...what would be the best tools to use?

Comment: @NCoder: have you looked at the documentation? `mysqldump` parameters are rather simple

Comment: @Ncoder See my original comment, which was "take this advice". This answer (use mysqldump) is good advice. Use cron to run mysqldump (or a simple bash script that calls mysqldump and does backup rotation and such).